# Splitting of a large graphics

Tags: graphics

I have large figures (PNG images) in my document that are very thin but block an entire page due to their length. Is there a package available that cuts those in half, and positions those halves next to each other as one figure?

Comment: Did you consider using `imagemagick`, you could batch the process and obtain the desired figures and insert them.

Comment: of course, using an external tool would also accomplish this. However, I'd like to use a more LaTeX-ish way of doing it. So that I only have to rebuild my document when changing the picture instead of 1) change picture 2) use tool to split 3) build pdf

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be quite easily done using Martin Scharrer's excellent `adjustbox` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\newcommand{\splitimage}[1]{%
  \adjustimage{trim=0 0.5\height{} 0 0, clip=true}{#1}%
  \adjustimage{trim=0 0 0 0.5\height{}, clip=true}{#1}%
}

\begin{document}
\splitimage{bottle}
\end{document}
```

---

Or using just the `graphicx` functionality:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\splitimage}[1]{%
  \newlength{\imageheight}%
  \settoheight{\imageheight}{\includegraphics{#1}}%
  \includegraphics[trim=0 0.5\imageheight{} 0 0, clip=true]{#1}%
  \includegraphics[trim=0 0 0 0.5\imageheight{}, clip=true]{#1}%
}

\begin{document}
\splitimage{bottle}

\end{document}
```

Image taken from Wikimedia Comons: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Normflasche-1.jpg

Answer (score 3):

you can clip anything of the image:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,multido}
\newlength\Iwidth\newlength\Iheight\newsavebox\IBox
\savebox\IBox{\includegraphics{Normflasche}}
\setlength\Iwidth{\wd\IBox} \setlength\Iheight{\ht\IBox}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\multido{\ry=0.5+-0.5, \rY=1.0+-0.5}{2}{%
  \multido{\rx=0.00+0.25, \rX=0.25+0.25}{4}{%
    \fbox{\includegraphics[%
       viewport={\rx\Iwidth} {\ry\Iheight} {\rX\Iwidth}  \rY\Iheight,clip,scale=0.5]{Normflasche}}} \\[2pt]%                                                                                                             
}                                                                                                                         

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In ConTeXt you can use the [`\clip`](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/clip) command. With `\setupclipping` you can select what to clip. Here I selected to clip into five slices on the vertical axis. With the `x=…` and `y=…` setting you specify which slice you want to retrieve.

```
\setupclipping
  [nx=1, ny=5]

\starttext

\dorecurse{5}{
  \clip[y=\recurselevel]{\externalfigure[hacker]}\blank}

\stoptext
```

result:

[image: result]

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\def\Columns{5}% columns
\def\Rows{5}% rows
\def\Filename{ParisHilton}
\def\Scale{1}

\newsavebox\IBox
\savebox\IBox{\includegraphics[scale=\Scale]{\Filename}}


\psset
{
    xunit=\dimexpr\wd\IBox/\Columns\relax,
    yunit=\dimexpr\ht\IBox/\Rows\relax,
}

\SpecialCoor
\begin{document}

\multido{\ny=\Rows+-1}{\Rows}
{
    \multido{\nx=0+1}{\Columns}
    {
        \pspicture(\Columns,\Rows)
            \psclip{\psframe[linestyle=none,linewidth=0pt](!\nx\space \ny\space 1 sub)(!\nx\space 1 add \ny)}
                \rput[bl](0,0){\usebox\IBox}
            \endpsclip
        \endpspicture
    }
}

\end{document}
```

Here is the [picture](http://resources3.news.com.au/images/2006/11/06/va1237219946211/Paris-Hilton-5295610.jpg) that I used in this answer as a demo picture.

Comment: Please focus on the code rather than on the sample picture.