# 4 images on a frame appearing each a a time - fine tuning beamer

Tags: beamer, graphics, pause

I have a figure which consists of 4 plots, [Full figure here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kpdr90vt8cwcsms/SRSF1_details_1fig.pdf), and I want to have them appearing one by-one in the presentation (from left to right, top to bottom). I managed to do this by including each plot separately using a combination of \subfloat and \pause:

```
\begin{frame} \frametitle{Cufflinks analysis - SRSF1}
  \begin{figure}[t]
    \centering
     \captionsetup[subfloat]{labelformat=empty}
      \subfloat[]{\label{} \includegraphics[scale = 0.20]{Image1.pdf}} 
      \pause \subfloat[]{\label{} \includegraphics[scale = 0.20]{Image2.pdf}}\\
      \pause \subfloat[]{\label{} \includegraphics[scale = 0.20]{Image3.pdf}}
      \pause \subfloat[]{\label{} \includegraphics[scale = 0.20]{Image4.pdf}}
  \end{figure}
\end{frame}
```

[edit] Result: [image: example]

The issue with this solution is that the vertical spacing between the rows of images is rather large. I would like to reduced it in order to increase the size of each image - better use of space really.

If someone has a simple alternative where all 4 plots are part of a single image and each part is uncovered when needed it would be great.

Be gentle, this is my 1st beamer presentation.

Comment: If the images aren't subject to change, you can probably achieve it by generating 4 big images corresponding to each step of the display : first with 1 image + 3 blank squares, second with 2 images + 2 blanks, etc. You can then use the `\only<...>` syntax to display them sequentially.

Comment: Interesting. And how would I go about creating/overlaying the blank squares?

Comment: You could use the image editor of your choice for that, but percusse's answer below is way more elegant and easy to set up.

Comment: [Splitting an image](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/70408/9467) might be useful for you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not much different than what you have already.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{mwe} % For dummy images
\usepackage{lmodern} % To suppress some warnings

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c@{}c}
 \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth,trim=0 120 160 0,clip]{example-image-a}\pause% 
&\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth,trim=160 120 0 0,clip]{example-image-a}\\[-1.5mm]\pause%
 \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth,trim=0 0 160 120,clip]{example-image-a}\pause%
&\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth,trim=160 0 0 120,clip]{example-image-a}
\end{tabular}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The trimming might not be good as I did it by eyeballing.

**EDIT** For the custom image, the following trim values seem to work.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lmodern} % To suppress some warnings

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c@{}c}
 \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth,trim=0 270 260 0,clip]{SRSF1_details_1fig}\pause% 
&\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth,trim=260 270 0 0,clip]{SRSF1_details_1fig}\\[-1.5mm]\pause%
 \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth,trim=0 0 260 265,clip]{SRSF1_details_1fig}\pause%
&\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth,trim=260 0 0 265,clip]{SRSF1_details_1fig}
\end{tabular}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How did you find `-1.5mm`?

Comment: @PaulGaborit Just a quick guess.

Comment: Thanks for the help @percusse, but it not really working for me. When I tested it I got superimposition of images in. Then I tried to check the trimming by trial and error using just one image:  `begin{frame} \frametitle{Cufflinks analysis - SRSF1}
  \centering
   \begin{tabular}{c@{}c}
  \includegraphics[scale = 0.48,trim=0 0 250 0,clip]{Image1.pdf}
 \end{tabular}
\end{frame} `. IN this case besides being clipped the image is also (bizarrely) relocated to the vertical centre.

Comment: @krespim trim entries goes like *left bottom right top*. Right now you are only trimming the right side with `0 0 250 0`. Can you upload you image to the question so that I can modify my answer?

Comment: @peruse: done. I've added the link to the figure (pdf)

Comment: @krespim Is it better now? The whitespace is because you don't trim enough. If you put boxes around your subplots trimming is always easier.

Comment: It working flawlessly @percusse! I could even increase the width to 0.4. In the meantime I've used your code with a few changes to have the 4 separate plots with less space between them: `\begin{frame}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c@{}c}
 \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{Image1}\pause% 
&\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{Image2}\\[-1.5mm]\pause%
 \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{Image3}\pause%
&\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{Image4}
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}`. This might be useful in the future but your solution is better. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Consider adding `\usepackage{adjustbox}` to the preamble, replacing `includegraphics` with `adjincludegraphics`, `120` with `{0.5\height}`, `160` with `{0.5\width}`, and voila, no more guessing about trimming 50% ([credit](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57420/224861)). See new answer for copy-able code.

Answer (score 4):

You could use *TikZ* and put the pictures in `node`s. With no `inner sep` or `outer sep` they align perfectly. If you need spacing, you can use `<position>=<distance>`, like `above right=3mm`

### Code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame} \frametitle{Cufflinks analysis - SRSF1}
  \begin{figure}[t]
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
                \node[above right,inner sep=0,outer sep=0] {\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{test}};\pause
                \node[above left,inner sep=0,outer sep=0] {\includegraphics[scale=0.65]{test}};\pause
                \node[below right,inner sep=0,outer sep=0] {\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{test}};\pause
                \node[below left=0.5cm,inner sep=0,outer sep=0] {\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{test}};
            \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
  \end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

### Result

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Building off of what @percusse described and [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57420/224861), you can get automatic 50% cropping by first loading `adjustbox` via `\usepackage{adjustbox}` and then:

```
\centering
  \begin{tabular}{c@{}c}
 \adjincludegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth,trim=0 {0.5\height} {0.5\width} 0,clip]{example-image-a}\pause% 
&\adjincludegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth,trim={0.5\width} {0.5\height} 0 0,clip]{example-image-a}\\[-1.5mm]\pause%
 \adjincludegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth,trim=0 0 {0.5\width} {0.5\height},clip]{example-image-a}\pause%
&\adjincludegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth,trim={0.5\width} 0 0 {0.5\height},clip]{example-image-a}
\end{tabular}
```

The behavior seems to be preserved (here's the 3rd frame):
[image]