# Add four images on a beamer frame

Tags: beamer, spacing, floats, two-column

What is the best way to add four images on a beamer frame? I am using

```
\documentclass[slidestop,compress,11pt,xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\definecolor{LHCblue}{RGB}{4, 114, 255}
\usecolortheme[named=LHCblue]{structure}
\usepackage[bars]{beamerthemetree} % Beamer theme v 2.2
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{marvosym}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{.49\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{figure}[H]
\includegraphics[width=5cm,height=3.5cm]{lab1}
\end{figure}
\hspace{0.7cm}
\centering
\begin{figure}[H]
\includegraphics[width=5cm,height=4cm]{lab2}
\end{figure}
\end{column}%
\hfill%
\begin{column}{.49\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=5cm,height=4cm]{lab3}\\
\includegraphics[width=5cm,height=4cm]{lab4}
\end{column}%
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The result is not the best...

[image]

Any possible ideas will be welcomed!

Comment: Why do you use `figure`? In your case I'd use a simple two column `tabular` with `\includegraphics` in each cell.

Comment: Related : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73626/4-images-on-a-frame-appearing-each-a-a-time-fine-tuning-beamer

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You don't really need the `figure` environment since you are not providing captions (`beamer`, in any case, deactivates the floating mechanism); so you can simply say:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{demo}{graphicx}
\documentclass[slidestop,compress,11pt,xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\definecolor{LHCblue}{RGB}{4, 114, 255}
\usecolortheme[named=LHCblue]{structure}
\usepackage[bars]{beamerthemetree} % Beamer theme v 2.2
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{marvosym}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}[t]
\column{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=5cm,height=3.5cm]{lab1}\\
\includegraphics[width=5cm,height=4cm]{lab2}
\column{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=5cm,height=4cm]{lab3}\\
\includegraphics[width=5cm,height=4cm]{lab4}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, you might need to adjust the width and or height of your images.

The line

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{demo}{graphicx}
```

was only included to replace actual figures with black rectangles; delete that line from your actual code.

On a side note, the `slidestop` class option is obsolete, so you should load the class using the `t` option instead:

```
\documentclass[t,compress,11pt,xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I like the simplicity of your solution!Nice!!! I played with the dimensions...I used `width=\columnwidth`. The thing is that the spacing between column is too much...In adition is there a way to space the images horizontally? I tried with `\hspace{}` but it isn't quite working...

Comment: What a cool solution!