# Add four images on a beamer frame with caption

Tags: beamer, captions

Can someone tell me how to put captions in the figure solution provided by @Gonzalo at [Add four images on a beamer frame](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74903/add-four-images-on-a-beamer-frame)

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gonzalo Medina said in the linked question that you don't need the `figure` environment if there are not captions. But inversely, you can use this environment if you want captions:

[image: wwe]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%just to simplifly the body of the document
\def\img#1{%
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=.2\textheight, keepaspectratio]% 
{example-image-#1} 
\caption{Caption of \MakeUppercase #1}
\end{figure}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{4 images}
\begin{columns}[t]
\column{.5\textwidth}
\img{a}\img{b}
\column{.5\textwidth}
\img{1x1}\img{c}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

If you are not happy with float behavior in Beamer, alternatively you can use the `\figcaption` of the `cattdef` package (or `\captionof{figure}{...}` of `caption` package, but not inside macro as in this example):

[image: mwe2]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{captdef}
%just to simplifly the body of the document
\newcommand\img[1]{%
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=.2\textheight, keepaspectratio]%
{example-image-#1}\par\figcaption{Caption of \MakeUppercase #1}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{4 images}
\begin{columns}[t]
\column{.5\textwidth}
\img{a}\img{b}
\column{.5\textwidth}
\img{1x1}\img{c}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```