# Panel Figure 2x2!

Tags: beamer, tabularx

How do the beamer a panel with 4 figure (2 x 2). As the following example: 
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

Improve this code:

```
  \documentclass{beamer}
  \usetheme{default}

 \begin{document}
 \begin{frame}{Panel figure 2 x 2!}
   \begin{minipage}{1\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[scale = 0.3]{example-image}
    \hfill
    \includegraphics[scale = 0.3]{example-image}
    \vspace{0.5cm}
    \includegraphics[scale = 0.3]{example-image}
    \hfill
    \includegraphics[scale = 0.3]{example-image}
  \end{minipage}

    Figure 1: \ldots
 \end{frame}

 \end{document}
```

Comment: How I could do to make the closest and centralized figures. Below I want to put the figure legend. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @WendellFialho The "correct" way to thank some one is to up-vote them. You should also give a green-tick to the person who supplies the best answer to your question. Note that you can, and should, up-vote the post that you give the green-tick to. I strongly encourage you to revisit your previous questions and up-vote accordingly.

Comment: Why `1\textwidth`?

Comment: @WendellFialho What do you mean? There is no legend in the image you posted. And which figures do you consider `closest` and `centralized` and what do you want to do with them!

Comment: @Wendell Fialho You should read this <http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/261469/add-four-images-on-a-beamer-frame-with-caption>