# show image one by one at a time

Tags: beamer, graphics

I have four images aligned in one slide and I want to show one picture at a time.

I was able to show the text using the code below

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Table of Contents}
\begin{itemize}
\item<1-> Introduction
\item<2-> Algorithm for reducing finite automata
\item<3-> Reliability models
\item<4-> Reduction steps
\item<5-> References
\item<6-> Conclusion
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

In the same way I want to show the images.

I have aligned the images as follows

```
\begin{frame}
\vcenteredhbox{\includegraphics[width=5cm,height=5cm,keepaspectratio]{pc5.jpg}}
\vcenteredhbox{\includegraphics[width=5cm,height=5cm,keepaspectratio]{pc6.jpg}}
\vcenteredhbox{\includegraphics[width=5cm,height=5cm,keepaspectratio]{pc8.jpg}}
\vcenteredhbox{\includegraphics[width=5cm,height=5cm,keepaspectratio]{pc7.jpg}}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: I think for this you can have a look to [4 images on a frame appearing each a a time fine tuning beamer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73626/4-images-on-a-frame-appearing-each-a-a-time-fine-tuning-beamer).

Comment: you can wrap them in `\only<3>{.....}` to show just on the third layer

Comment: It would be useful if you show the definition of `\vcenteredhbox` or add a pointer for it.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe with `\alt` and `\phantom`, assuming you used the custom definition for `\vcenteredhbox`, that I found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17102/17775).

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand*{\vcenteredhbox}[1]{\begingroup
\setbox0=\hbox{#1}\parbox{\wd0}{\box0}\endgroup}


\newcommand{\thepic}{\includegraphics[width=5cm,height=5cm,keepaspectratio]{pic.png}}

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}
 \vcenteredhbox{\thepic}
 \vcenteredhbox{\alt<2->{\thepic}{\phantom{\thepic}}}
 \vcenteredhbox{\alt<3->{\thepic}{\phantom{\thepic}}}
 \vcenteredhbox{\alt<4->{\thepic}{\phantom{\thepic}}}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe just `uncover` would be sufficient.

```
\documentclass[demo]{beamer}

\newcommand*{\vcenteredhbox}[1]{#1}

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}
\vcenteredhbox{\includegraphics[width=5cm,height=5cm,keepaspectratio]{pc5.jpg}}
\uncover<2->{\vcenteredhbox{\includegraphics[width=5cm,height=5cm,keepaspectratio]{pc6.jpg}}}
\uncover<3->{\vcenteredhbox{\includegraphics[width=5cm,height=5cm,keepaspectratio]{pc8.jpg}}}
\uncover<4->{\vcenteredhbox{\includegraphics[width=5cm,height=5cm,keepaspectratio]{pc7.jpg}}}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]